# Memory-exceeding on import in py2neo

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, heap-memory, py2neo

I am using py2neo to import a large graph.

This consists of over 10M records and relationships.

As these are being imported via:

```
tx = graph.begin()
...
tx.commit()
```

it seems like the memory used by the transaction is not being released. This brings about to the max memory cap of my machine being reached and making the whole creation process very slow from then onwards.